# android live uploading

Tags: android, video, live

How to upload a live video(instantaneous video capturing from camera) to a web server in android.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct API access to raw video data.

Android's [MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) creates a file. You could continuously read that file and send data to the server. This does not work perfectly - on some phones MediaRecorder updates this file (= flushes data to file) very sporadically. You could see delays of between 10-30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a client software to capture the stream from the camera. Surely, you could use an RTSP client or a MMS. In addition, the Web server must be able to store the stream that you send to the server.

Regards!